# C# use ints in other classes

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to coding and would like some help
So I'm trying to make a % calculator: In textbox 1 you enter, say, "75%" then in textbox 2 you put in, for example, "1000" in textbox 3 it will say 750.

But my problem is that now only when I edit textbox 2 the third one change I want to be able to modify value in the txtbox1.

```
   public void xylosTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

        Int32 val1 = Convert.ToInt32(xylosTextBox1.Text);
        Int32 val2 = Convert.ToInt32(xylosTextBox2.Text);
        Int32 val3 = val2 * val1 / 100;
        Int32 val5 = val1 + val2;

        int t1 = Convert.ToInt32(xylosTextBox1.Text);
        int t2 = Convert.ToInt32(xylosTextBox2.Text);
        int t3 = val5; 
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        if (val5 > 1)
        {
            xylosTextBox3.Text = val3.ToString();
        }


    }
```

Now when I go to

```
private void xylosTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

And try to input if val5 > 1 it says it doesn't recognize val5

```
private void xylosTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            if (val5 > 1)
            {
                xylosTextBox3.Text = val3.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Your answer is too broad for stackoverflow, you'd be better off reading [Variable and Method Scope in Microsoft .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Comment: Those are not class variables, they are local variables (in the scope of `xylosTextBox2_TextChanged`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add same EventHandler of your xylosTextBox2 to your xylosTextBox1. That way regardless whenever you update your first or second textbox first, you will do the calculations and update your third textbox.

```
xylosTextBox1.TextChanged += xylosTextBox2_TextChanged;
xylosTextBox2.TextChanged += xylosTextBox2_TextChanged;
```

As a note, if you go with this, you should change the name of the xylosTextBox2_TextChanged to something more apropriate.

Answer (score 3):

If you declare a variable inside `xylosTextBox2_TextChanged()` then it can't be seen by `xylosTextBox1_TextChanged()`. You have to declare it outside the method:

```
int val1, val2, val3, val4, val5;

public void xylosTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    val1 = Convert.ToInt32(xylosTextBox1.Text);
    val2 = Convert.ToInt32(xylosTextBox2.Text);
    val3 = val2 * val1 / 100;
    val5 = val1 + val2;

    int t1 = Convert.ToInt32(xylosTextBox1.Text);
    int t2 = Convert.ToInt32(xylosTextBox2.Text);
    int t3 = val5; 
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if (val5 > 1)
    {
        xylosTextBox3.Text = val3.ToString();
    }


}
```

Comment: Error 6 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'CSGO_Value.Form1.xylosTextBox1' 
I get this error when i do so ?

Comment: Don't initialize the values outside of the method.